# Making multiple individual line graphs in Excel

Tags: excel, loops, line

I have a Excel database that contains a list of schools and their weekly enrollment rate, like so:

```
            5-Sep   12-Sep  19-Sep  26-Sep  3-Oct   10-Oct
School A    507     510     505     509     508     504
School B    442     447     445     443     439     438
School C    1281    1297    1307    1308    1297    1294
School D    376     365     358     353     353     350
```

In total, I have 39 schools (rows) and 43 dates (columns), but I didn't think it was necessary to show all of it.  What I need to do is make an individual line graph for enrollment for each individual school.  Since the x-axis (dates) will be the same for each graph, is there a way to tell Excel to run a loop to go through each row and make the line graph?  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sparkline feature in Excel 2007 (I think) and later.

Your data:
[image]

Go to Insert>>Sparklines and click "Line":
[image]

Highlight your first line's data:
[image]

Hit OK, and then copy that down as if it were a formula:
[image]

Bob's your uncle:
[image]

There's plenty of options for changing how those are displayed too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scatter plot. Select the entire data range then choose: Insert\Scatter\YourPreferredScatterType. [image]